# font size change after orientation screen change to horizontal

Tags: iphone, fonts, size

i have build application web on iphone, but the font size is change it to large when i rotate my iphone..

anybody know how to keep size the font?

thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer..

To ignore the change of font size on rotation, simply add

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

Comment: But why does 'span' tag resize text on rotation and 'a' tag not?!